# Output POST requests(JSON data) made to my webhook url?

Tags: node.js, json, webhooks

I want to output POST requests made to my webhook url(which is a local server that is exposed with ngrok). I want to output JSON data whenever a POST request is made to my webhook url.

Comment: You have all this crazy technology running but you don't know how to send data back as a response? What does your webhook response look like? Show the code where you tried to flush some output as a response. Also please show the code seperating POST/GET.

Comment: I'm actually writing a viber chatbot. I registered the webhook url to my ngrok server so whenever I typed a message in the Viber chat channel the post data with the information about the user is sent to the webhook url. I want to output that data. I have not written any response for the webhook.

Comment: Well then read about basics how to output data? https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server

Comment: Thanks I get it now. Thank you for your time.